# Converting a Google Sketchup file to 3DS?

Tags: 3d, models, file-format

I have a couple models that I've made or found in Google Sketchup, and I want to be able to use them in some programs I have that only support 3DS.  What is the best way to convert, without paying for Sketchup Pro?

Right now sketchup can export to .dae, so a .dae to 3ds would be just as helpful :)

Comment: 3DS meaning 3d Studio Max?

Comment: He means 3DS file format, the de facto format of old versions of 3D Studio MAX.

Comment: Yep, that got me too when I first read it

Answer (score 2):

Download Autodesk's free FBX Converter. Convert your COLLADA file to FBX, and then select the newly exported file. You will see that the program now gives you more export formats, including 3DS.

http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/pc/item?siteID=123112&id=10775855